# RocketMQ Consumer request offset is much bigger than max offset in broker and Consumer Diff is negative

Tags: rocketmq

RocketMQ version: 3.2.6

Our cluster:

- 2 NameServer
- 6 Master Broker
- 6 Slave Broker

We have a lot of consumers(about 100) consume message from broker ,

1. We use command to monitor consume diff  command:
   /data/alibaba-rocketmq/bin/mqadmin  consumerProgress -n XXX:XX The
   diff is negative (eg: -898232391123,-8323231872) in only one
   broker,other brokers is healthy.
2. A lot of broker warn log below

[a lot of errors : Consumer request offset is much bigger than max offset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2L1Zi.png)

[a lot of errors : connection reset frequently](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gxtIc.png)

Answer (score 1):

finally，I found the answer in github
https://github.com/alibaba/RocketMQ/releases

It's a bug  and fixed in version  3.4.6. That's ok.